# Unable to drag and drop using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I need to reorder rows by drag and drop, which is draggable.

I tried with the below code, its not working.

```
this.reOrderMenu=function(menuName,order){
    var self=this;

    this.gridRow.filter(function(row){
        return row.$$('td').get(1).getText().then(function(name){
            return name===menuName;
        });
    }).then(function(selected){
        selected[0].$$('td:nth-child(1)').then(function(eles){
            browser.actions().mouseDown(eles[0]).perform();
            browser.actions().mouseMove(eles[0]).perform();
            browser.actions().mouseMove(self.gridRow.get(order)).perform();
            browser.actions().mouseUp(self.gridRow.get(order)).perform();  
            browser.sleep(3000);   
        });                  

    });

};
```

I'm calling the below method as,

```
it('TS_002, Get the menu order number before changing', function () {

    var orderAfter;
    menuConfig.findOrder(menuName).then(function(text){
        orderAfter=text-2;
        expect(text).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        browser.refresh();
        menuConfig.selectApplication(testData.selectAppName);
        menuConfig.reOrderMenu(menuName,orderAfter);
    });      


});
```

It doesn't show any error, but the drag functionality doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain all the actions first and finally call the `perform()` method.

can you try the below snippet,

```
browser
      .actions()
      .mouseMove(eles[0])
      .mouseDown()
      .mouseMove(self.gridRow.get(order))
      .mouseUp()
      .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Html-dnd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd)

Try to use this module for HTML5 drag and drop simulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(elem,target).mouseUp().perform();(Protractor)
```

elem is the element which needs to dragged

target is the destination.